# Error: SWF from http://xx.xxx.xxx.xx/vw.swf?nocache=1.1 may not connect to a socket in its own domain without a policy file

Tags: actionscript-3, sockets, cross-domain, flash

Im getting this error every now and then. I mean its not coming always some times it gives error and some times it doesnt.
I have checked all other similar posts but no solution worked!!

my crossdomain xml is at the root of the domain and is

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
    <!DOCTYPE cross-domain-policy SYSTEM "http://www.adobe.com/xml/dtds/cross-domain-policy.dtd">
    <cross-domain-policy>
      <site-control permitted-cross-domain-policies="master-only"/>
      <allow-access-from to-ports="*" domain="*" secure="false"/>
    </cross-domain-policy>
```

And in actionScipt ive got

```
Security.allowDomain("*");
Security.loadPolicyFile("./crossdomain.xml");
```

And still getting the below error,

```
Warning: Timeout on xmlsocket://xx.xxx.xxx.xx:843 (at 3 seconds) while waiting for socket policy file.  This should not cause any problems, but see http://www.adobe.com/go/strict_policy_files for an explanation.
## SecurityError: [SecurityErrorEvent type="securityError" bubbles=false cancelable=false eventPhase=2 text="Error #2048: Security sandbox violation: http://xx.xxx.xxx.xx/vw.swf?nocache=1.1 cannot load data from xx.xxx.xxx.xx:9933."]
Warning: Timeout on xmlsocket://xx.xxx.xxx.xx:9933 (at 3 seconds) while waiting for socket policy file.  This should not cause any problems, but see http://www.adobe.com/go/strict_policy_files for an explanation.
Error: SWF from http://xx.xxx.xxx.xx/vw.swf?nocache=1.1 may not connect to a socket in its own domain without a policy file.  See http://www.adobe.com/go/strict_policy_files to fix this problem.
*** Security Sandbox Violation ***
Connection to xx.xxx.xxx.xx:9933 halted - not permitted from http://xx.xxx.xxx.xx/vw.swf?nocache=1.1
```

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

It will not work. Your socket server should return crossdomain policy file, so your socket connection can be established. For example simple [PHP realisation](http://www.functionblog.com/?p=67=1) - 90 line of code.

Comment: I didnt get you, I have got crossdomain.xml at root of my domain. And as I said earlier the error is random, sometimes it comes sometimes it doesnt

Comment: If you want to work with sockets, your implementation of socket server, also must return crossdomain policy file. Flash client should get policy file through socket connection.

Comment: Hey I havent got much idea about socket concept and your answer is going over my head. Can please tell me how exactly to achieve this..? thanks

Comment: Do you have a contact of person who develops socket server that you are working with? Or what kind of socket server do you use?

Comment: Im using smartFox server 2X, 
<socket address="xx.xxx.xx.xx" port="9933" type="TCP"/>
<socket address="xx.xxx.xx.xx" port="9933" type="UDP"/>

Comment: Great, check this out: `SFS2X can automatically serve the policy file via socket. The file is located at SFS2X/config/crossdomain.xml and can be edited to meet your requirements.`

Comment: Yes I did see that, but somehow still not working. I tried to run a perl script also as stated in adobe site and still not able to send the cross domain policy file through 843 port. And the error is still rocking :(. Also the error doesnt show up always.